# jquery next() and find() to remove class from element doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently having a problem:

I have different elements in my html. All except the first one having a class called "inactive" and I want them click by click (on each cell) to become active (remove "inactive" attribute).

Clicking the first, will activate the second. Clicking the second, will activate the third. And so on.

Here is my html.

```
<div class="around">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row inactive">
        <div class="cell">text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row inactive">
        <div class="cell">text 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my jquery (found that on stackoverflow)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".cell" ).click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.around').next().find('.inactive').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

This will do... nothing.

I also tried:

```
$(this).closest('.around').find('.inactive').removeClass('inactive');
    });
```

But this will remove "inactive" class from all elements

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to removeclass from parent of clicked element, You need to traverse to parent element using `.parent()` :

```
$( ".cell" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('inactive');
});
```

If you want to remove the class from next sibling element of clicked parent, then use `.parent()` along with `.next()`:

```
$( ".cell" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Comment: You can remove it again it was not asked, the next() part was code copied from another question on stackoverflow. He really needs the parent element and not the next one

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry. In fact I need the next element to be activated by clicking an element. Milind gave the helping answer to this.

Answer (score 6):

Use [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".cell" ).click(function() {
        // Take the parent .row element of the selected cell
        // and remove the class .inactive
        $(this).parent('.row').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that piece of code he has copied from somewhere else, I don't think he wants the next row